# How to get value from index property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, hashmap, namespaces

Here is my code:

```
const array1 = [{a: 'abc', b: 'cd'}, {a: 'abc', b: 'xyz'}, {a: 'abc', 
b: 'mno'}];
let obj = array1.reduce(function(result, item, index){
    result[index] = item
  return result;
}, {});

let dealId = 123;
let value = {};
let array2 = [];
for (var property in obj) {
   value[dealId] = array2.push(obj[property]);
}
console.log(value)
```

The output of this is 
`Object { 123: 3 }`

But I want and this is what I was expecting. 

`Object { 123: [{a: 'abc', b: 'cd'}, {a: 'abc', b: 'xyz'}, {a: 'abc', b: 'mno'}] }`

Why am I getting 3 instead of an array? How to get the array?

Comment: Push returns the new length of the array. Move the assignment outside the loop. Also, you can simply use `Object.values(obj)` instead (with a difference that inherited properties won't be listed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array, not the array itself. Your loop assigns the values 1, 2 and 3 to the same `value[dealId]`.

Instead, you can move the assignment outside the loop:

```
for (var property in obj) {
   array2.push(obj[property]);
}
value[dealId] = array2;
```

Or you can simply use `Object.values`:

```
value[dealId] = Object.values(obj);
```

But note that this does not list inherited properties.

Answer (score 1):

Why not build a new object with a single key and the given array as value?

For the object use a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```js
const
    array = [{ a: 'abc', b: 'cd' }, { a: 'abc', b: 'xyz' }, { a: 'abc', b: 'mno' }],
    key = 123,
    object = { [key]: array };

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: but his expected key is without `""`. Expected is `123` not `"123"`

Comment: @VicJordan, the keys of objects are always strings.

Comment: Yes I know but I think it would be better if we can tell the same to OP i.e. this information in your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add into aaray first then create the object

```js
 

const array1 = [{a: 'abc', b: 'cd'}, {a: 'abc', b: 'xyz'}, {a: 'abc', b: 'mno'}];
let obj = array1.reduce(function(result, item, index){
    result[index] = item
  return result;
}, {});

let dealId = 123;
let value = {};
let array2 = [];
for (var property in obj) {
  array2.push(obj[property]);
}
 value[dealId] = array2;
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array1 = [{a: 'abc', b: 'cd'}, {a: 'abc', b: 'xyz'}, {a: 'abc', 
b: 'mno'}];
let obj = array1.reduce(function(result, item, index){
    result[index] = item
  return result;
}, {});

let dealId = 123;
let value = {};
let array2 = [];
for (var property in obj) {
   array2.push(obj[property]);
}

value[dealId] = array2;

console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign your new obj property (id) the requested array:

```
    let arr = [{a: 'abc', b: 'cd'}, {a: 'abc', b: 'xyz'}, {a: 'abc', 
    b: 'mno'}];
    let newObj = {};
    let id = 123;

    newObj[id] = arr;
    console.log(newObj);
```